# mysql "sounds like" with "order by"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that finds similar sounding names, but I need to order the results by most similar sounding at the top, is there a way to do that?

```
SELECT `Table_Name_2`.`Id`, `Table_Name_2`.`Name` 
FROM `Table_Name` 
JOIN `Table_Name_2` ON `Table_Name`.`Id` = `Table_Name_2`.`Id` 
WHERE `Table_Name_2`.`Name` SOUNDS LIKE ? 
OR `Table_Name`.`NamePortion` SOUNDS LIKE ?
ORDER BY **[HOW TO SORT BY MOST SOUNDS LIKE]** DESC
```

Table_Name

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id                  | Name                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1                   | aba                 |
| 1                   | jim                 |
| 2                   | abi                 |
| 2                   | jin                 |
| 3                   | foo                 |
| 3                   | bar                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Table_Name_2

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id                  | Name                |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1                   | aba jim             |
| 2                   | abi jin             |
| 3                   | foo bar             |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

desired results when searching "abi":

```
0 => 2, abi jin
1 => 1, aba jim
```

Thank you!

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: Try if the function [SOUNDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) is something for your.

Comment: `sounds like` is binary.  It does not provide a measure of similarity.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there a solution you can recommend?

Comment: @Tom . . . It sounds like you probably want Levenshtein distance.